# Correlation between Values in R

Tags: r

need some help with some R scripting.

I import a Dataframe via read.csv which looks like that:

[image: Table]

Each value is a PlayerID and each row is a lineup.

My goal is to have a correlation of each lineup (row) between PlayerIDs. Basically I want to calculate which combinations of playerids are most common used per lineup (row).

I tried the correlate() function but it will only correlate the columns.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
dput was asked:

```
    > dput(df)
structure(list(D = c(22119364L, 22119376L, 22119376L, 22119372L, 
22119372L, 22119372L, 22119372L, 22119373L, 22119372L, 22119372L
), D.1 = c(22119376L, 22119394L, 22119372L, 22119371L, 22119373L, 
22119371L, 22119371L, 22119371L, 22119373L, 22119371L), D.2 = c(22119394L, 
22119386L, 22119373L, 22119380L, 22119375L, 22119381L, 22119375L, 
22119395L, 22119380L, 22119381L), D.3 = c(22119386L, 22119378L, 
22119375L, 22119370L, 22119371L, 22119370L, 22119380L, 22119375L, 
22119375L, 22119370L), D.4 = c(22119378L, 22119365L, 22119396L, 
22119375L, 22119395L, 22119375L, 22119396L, 22119370L, 22119395L, 
22119375L), D.5 = c(22119370L, 22119368L, 22119371L, 22119395L, 
22119379L, 22119395L, 22119370L, 22119380L, 22119370L, 22119396L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Edit:
Combination question:
Also may I ask are you want to see which pair (2 players) are more popular or which combinations (any comb from 2 to 5)

Any combination would be interesting

Edit: Have you tried transposing your data before computing the correlation? cor(t(df))

```
             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]        [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]       [,9]      [,10]
 [1,]  1.00000000  0.3467029 -0.01573126 -0.1370310 -0.03689795 -0.1049490  0.2446885  0.6252798  0.3330059 -0.1159602
 [2,]  0.34670287  1.0000000 -0.57933025 -0.4193527 -0.65817923 -0.4005822 -0.5205894  0.2304352 -0.3852697 -0.4037538
 [3,] -0.01573126 -0.5793303  1.00000000 -0.2454127  0.88159245 -0.2529465  0.9503422 -0.4211406  0.9226407 -0.2566678
 [4,] -0.13703100 -0.4193527 -0.24541275  1.0000000  0.19802504  0.9991003 -0.2804525  0.4335783 -0.2075516  0.9996144
 [5,] -0.03689795 -0.6581792  0.88159245  0.1980250  1.00000000  0.1907837  0.8156830 -0.2392496  0.8537408  0.1869590
 [6,] -0.10494905 -0.4005822 -0.25294651  0.9991003  0.19078368  1.0000000 -0.2834194  0.4701357 -0.2003660  0.9998520
 [7,]  0.24468850 -0.5205894  0.95034220 -0.2804525  0.81568296 -0.2834194  1.0000000 -0.3059578  0.9415746 -0.2878249
 [8,]  0.62527976  0.2304352 -0.42114058  0.4335783 -0.23924963  0.4701357 -0.3059578  1.0000000 -0.1066355  0.4581980
 [9,]  0.33300586 -0.3852697  0.92264065 -0.2075516  0.85374076 -0.2003660  0.9415746 -0.1066355  1.0000000 -0.2092557
[10,] -0.11596019 -0.4037538 -0.25666781  0.9996144  0.18695898  0.9998520 -0.2878249  0.4581980 -0.2092557  1.0000000
```

This helps seeing coorelation between the lineups. Where I'm just hanging, seeing correlations per playerid through all lineups. Is it possible that I have the same output but instead of lineups(rows) per playerid (value) ?

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(Dataframe name)`?

Comment: sure: > dput(df)
structure(list(D = c(22119364L, 22119376L, 22119364L, 22119376L, 
22119372L, 22119364L, 22119376L, 22119364L, 22119376L, 22119364L, 
22119364L, 22119372L, 22119372L, 22119376L, 22119376L, 22119376L, 
22119364L, 22119364L, 22119376L, 22119376L, 22119364L, 22119376L, 
22119364L, 22119376L, 22119376L, 22119376L, 22119364L, 22119376L,  ...

Comment: @Joaggi please post it in your question instead of the comment.

Comment: Have you tried transposing your data before computing the correlation? `cor(t(df))`

Comment: @Joaggi - instead of an image of dput - may you put in the actual text quote in a code block (```) - Also may I ask are you want to see which pair (2 players) are more popular or which combinations (any comb from 2 to 5)

Comment: sorry Guys ;) newbie in this world and just starting playing around with R :D will modify it now

Comment: As suggested by Vincent, this is likely a duplicate of: [correlation by row, within data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016982/correlation-by-row-within-data-frame)

Comment: thx will have a look at this other thread